# Solve $\int _{|z-1|=1} \frac{\log{z}}{z^{4}} dz $

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

this problem came in my exam today and I couldn't solve it.
This is my failed attempt, using Cauchy's Integral Formula for derivatives.

I think that the theorem tells me that if $z_ {0} \in $ my curve or on the curve itself, I can apply this formula, where
$$\int _{|z-1|=1} \frac{\log{z}}{(z+0)^{4}} dz $$
$$f(z)=\log{z} ,   \text{main branch} $$
$$z_0=0,  n+1=4$$[image]

Since z_0 is on the curve

$$f'''(0)=\int _{|z-1|=1} \frac{3!}{2\pi i}\frac{\log{z}}{(z+0)^{4}} dz$$

Now, My problem is that the third derivative of $f (z) $ is $2/z^3$

But, I still have an indeterminacy and I did not know how to advance, am I using the theorem wrong?

A huge apology and thank you so much for the help

Comment: It's actually not your fault, the original integral is undefined.

Comment: I will thank you very much if you explain me, please :payge:

Comment: $\log 0 =$? And your contour contains the point....?